# Loop in KO magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

i have created steps on checkout page and every step has number like 1 2 and 3 now i want to create those number through a loop like

> $i = 1; $i++

how i can do this in KO Js.

image is attached http://prntscr.com/n8x2so

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate to observable array Using

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        people: [
            { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
            { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
            { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Dentiste' }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

For more example check out [KOdocumentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)